# Replacing date with EPOCH in column output

Tags: awk, printf

I have a set of data like so:

```
user1 1234 01/01/2020
user2 2345 02/02/2020
```

I need to convert the third column (date) to EPOCH while retaining the username and id number.

```
user1 1234 1577862000
user2 2345 1580626800
```

I have been able to get the conversion and printing working, but the new date is being appended to a new line.

```
$awk '{print($1,$2)}; system("date -d "$3" +%s")' data
user1 1234
1577862000
user2 2345
1580626800
```

How can I get the new EPOCH date to be on the same line with columns 1 & 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`print` appends a newline by default. Use `printf`:

```
awk '{printf "%s %s ",$1,$2; system("date -d "$3" +%s")}' data
```

If a special output field separator `OFS` had been defined, you could use

```
awk '{printf "%s%s%s%s",$1,OFS,$2,OFS; system("date -d "$3" +%s")}' data
```

Notice that each `%s` gets one of the remaining arguments to `printf`.

Output:

```
user1 1234 1577847600
user2 2345 1580612400
```

Comment: It is working for a few input lines but spawns a subshell for each line. Using perl (or gnu awk) time functions will be many order of magnitude faster and easier on the CPU

Answer (score 6):

If you have GNU awk (aka `gawk`) you could use its built-in time `mktime` function (although the input date format needs some manipulation first):

```
$ gawk 'split($3,a,"/") {$3 = mktime(sprintf("%04d %02d %02d 00 00 00",a[3],a[2],a[1]))} 1' data
user1 1234 1577854800
user2 2345 1580619600
```

Alternatively, Miller provides a C-style `strptime` and `strftime`:

```
$ mlr --nidx put '$3 = strftime(strptime($3,"%d/%m/%Y"),"%s")' data
user1 1234 1577854800
user2 2345 1580619600
```

or similarly in Perl, with the Time::Piece module:

```
$ perl -MTime::Piece -alne '
    $t = pop @F; print join " ", @F, Time::Piece->strptime($t,"%d/%m/%Y")->strftime("%s")
  ' data
user1 1234 1577854800
user2 2345 1580619600
```

Comment: Nice alternative, thanks for sharing. I believe the zero-padding is not necessary here?

Comment: @Quasímodo looks like you're right, I seemed to remember having to do that before but must be mistaken

Comment: @Alex: that one doesn't spawn a shell for each lines of input. It will be much faster if your input files has more than a few lines.